# python 3, regex returns a different result for same string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a code that looks like this

```
import re

s = "farmer’s boy of s...=--ixpence."
b = "farmer's boy of s...=--ixpence."
s_replaced = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z' ]+", '', s)
b_replaced = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z' ]+", '', b)
print(s_replaced)
print(b_replaced)

>>> farmers boy of sixpence
>>> farmer's boy of sixpence
```

I was trying to write a code that eliminates all punctuation except for apostrophe, and I don't understand why regex is returning different results for a same set of string. Why is this happening?

Comment: Those strings are not the same.

Comment: Look carefully at those strings. `’` is not the same as `'`.

Comment: `>>> "farmer’s boy of s...=--ixpence." == "farmer's boy of s...=--ixpence."
False`

Comment: oh wow this is stupid... I was struggling over this for two hours.... it wasn't apparent on my PyCharm font! Thanks you tho

Comment: @EricKim You should probably do a check before hand of `s` and `b`, something like `if s == b:`, to ensure both strings are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings are not the same.

`s` contains a `’` while `b` contains a `'`. `[^a-zA-Z' ]` matches anything that is not `a-z`, `A-Z`, `'`, or  (a space). This matches `’`, which is in `s`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `s` and `b` are not the same, since they both contain different apostrophes, `’` and `'`. This can easily be checked:

```
>>> s = "farmer’s boy of s...=--ixpence."
>>> b = "farmer's boy of s...=--ixpence."
>>> s == b
False
>>> print([x for x in s if x not in b])
['’']
```

Which shows that `s` contains an `'’'` apostrophe, but `b` does not. To ensure that only equal strings are compared, you need to do a preliminary `==` check beforehand:

```
s = "farmer’s boy of s...=--ixpence."
b = "farmer's boy of s...=--ixpence."

if s == b:
   print("Both strings are equal")
   # Rest of code here
```

Which checks if the values of `s` and `b` are the same before doing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The first string is a right single quotation mark, the second is an apostrophe. You can check the characters value [here](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.html)